# How to create Class diagram automatically while using Pycharm community eddition?

Tags: python, pycharm, uml, class-diagram

I'm using Pycharm **community edition**, and want to generate class diagrams automatically based on the classes that exist in my project.
I tried to use **PlantUML plugin**, but unfortunately, I need to create the class diagrams by creating a file with plantUML's syntax.

I want to be able to generate the classes diagrams **automatically** from the project, so when a class structure is changed, the diagram will be changed as well.

For example, in Intellijay IDE this could be achieved by selecting the class from the project tool window, then click on "Diagrams"...

How can this be done in Pycharm community edition (In the professional edition it is pretty simple)?

Thank you.